# flex and bison and readline: weird segment fault

Tags: bison, readline, flex-lexer

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5-ubuntu
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /path/to/drcalc...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /path/to/cdrcalc 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7e606b6 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb)
```

Anybody can help? My code can be downloaded at https://github.com/dramforever/drcalc/ branch `readline`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I am the asker!)
I don't know anything about readline. so a good function definetion will work.
I chose https://github.com/jterrace/craq/blob/master/gmp-4.3.1/demos/calc/calcread.c

Answer (score 2):

You should compile with the **-g** flag, so gdb is able to display more debug information. If you do that, you will see that the program crashes in the function **inp_readline**, when trying to use **sh_line**, which is NULL.

The reason is that you give **sh_line** 0 (which will be interpreted as a NULL pointer) as its initial value, and then in **inp_readline** you check if **sh_line** is non-NULL, and in that case you free the old string and read a new one with **readline**. But if it is NULL, which it is at the start, nothing is done, so when you get to **strlen(sh_line)** it is still NULL, and **strlen** crashes.

**EDIT:**

In the original, it says

```
if (sh_line) free(sh_line);sh_line=0; 
sh_line = readline(sh_Prompt);
```

but you added some braces so it instead says

```
if (sh_line) {free(sh_line);sh_line=0;
sh_line = readline(sh_Prompt);}
```

That's why **readline** never gets called.

Comment: So how should I fix it? I know nothing about readline and just did a copy-paste-edit from http://parafeed.googlecode.com/svn-history/r32/trunk/code/shell.l

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it in another way.